# Serial IO with posix and write to shared memory

Tags: c++, serial-port, posix, shared-memory

I got a problem with a posix signal, that I use for reading serial data. First here is a small example code how I initialize my serial port, my signal and a shared memory.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <QSharedMemory>

int fd;
struct termios termAttr;
struct sigaction saio;
char buff[255];
QSharedMemory QShare("IDSTRINGOFTHISMEMORY");

void signal_handler_IO (int status)
{
std::cout << "Got Serial Data!" << std::endl;
int si = read(fd, &buff[0], 255);

if(true) // Works with false here, but then the shared memory ist not used!
{
    char TWrite = 't';
    QShare.lock();
    char *to = (char*)QShare.data();
    const char *from = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&TWrite);
    memcpy(to, from, 1);
    QShare.unlock();
}
}

int main()
{
// Create SharedMemory:
QShare.create(1);

fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if (fd == -1)
{
    return -1;
}


saio.sa_handler = signal_handler_IO;
saio.sa_flags = 0;
saio.sa_restorer = NULL;
sigemptyset(&saio.sa_mask);
sigaddset(&saio.sa_mask, SIGINT);
sigaction(SIGIO,&saio,NULL);

fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY|FASYNC);
fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());

tcgetattr(fd,&termAttr);

cfsetospeed(&termAttr,B57600);
cfsetispeed(&termAttr,B57600);


termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
termAttr.c_cc[VMIN]     = 5;
tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&termAttr);
while(true)
{
    usleep(1000000);
}
return 0;
}
```

I had this code in use for a while and it did work quite well. Now for a different project I want to store the serial data in shared memory block, so I can read the current datapoint from multiple processes. In the `signal_handler_IO` I try to write the data to a shared memory that is created by sys/shm.h. The moment I started using shared memory the posix signal stopped working. Since I was unsure about the use of the shared memory I also tried to use the QSharedMemory class from qt, which created the same result.

Can you tell me, what the shared memory does to my posix signal?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, including how you set up not only the serial port but also how you set up the shared memory and what the signal handler is doing. Then we will probably be able to help you more directly by telling you where in your code the problem is and how you might fix it. Because signals, serial port and shared memory are three different things that should not be connected and affect each other like you claim.

Comment: I edited the question, but you will net a serial testdevice to run it.

Comment: I suggest you check the return value of QSharedMemory.create() and see if the shared memory is attached properly. One more thing you can try is removing the lock and unlock segment, I feel that the lock is not released properly in your previous execution.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "not working" part? ***How*** is it not working with the shared memory? What happens? What is supposed to happen? How do you check if "it is working" or not?

Comment: This example seems to behave a litte different to my original one. But you are right the attach() is missing. With that it works because it can work on the shared memory I created in one of the first tests. So since this example works I have to have a look at my code and see what is wrong there. Thank you!